# Can anyone identify this faux brick wall material?

Tags: walls

I bought a new house in the summer 2023 and would like to paint over this faux brick wall. I am wondering what type of material this is, and if I need a special type of paint (besides regular wall paint) for this.

To me it looks like stucco or something, but I want to be sure as I have no idea what I’m doing.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like (already painted over at least once) perfectly normal fake brick (thin sliced brick - Z-brick or competitors) so pretty much the same as painting anything else that's already painted.

Comment: Samarra, your question seems to really be how to paint the wall. You might revise to ask that instead.

Comment: I think it's real bricks...just thin ones. Paint away!   I would wire brush it and wipe it with a TSP solution.

Comment: check your crawlspace for some leftover materials (a common place where half a packet of left-over tiles end up, there might be some that you can take to a local paint store for advice.

Answer (score 1):

It's not neat enough to be a stamp, so my bet is it's actually brick with semi-gloss or high-gloss paint.

Painting it should be easy enough.

1. scuff sand it with 150-220 grit
2. Add some decent latex primer